# Dimension of a semilocal Hilbert ring is zero

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

> Is the Krull dimension of any commutative semilocal Hilbert ring equal to zero?

I appreciate any help from anyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the answer is *trivially* yes: by definition, a prime ideal is an intersection of maximal ideals; since your ring is semilocal, there are only finitely many such maximal ideals, so the given prime contains a maximal one, end of story.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is *yes*.

Hopefully the argument below isn't nonsense:

---

Let $A$ be such a ring.  To determine its Krull dimension it is no loss of generality
to quotient out by the nilradical, and thus suppose that $A$ is reduced.

Thus, since $A$ is semi-local, it has finitely many maximal ideals, say $\mathfrak m_1, \ldots, \mathfrak m_n$, whose intersection is trivial (because the Jacobson radical of $A$ equals the nilradical, which is trivial).   But then
the map $A \mapsto A/\mathfrak m_1 \times \cdots \times A/\mathfrak m_n$ is an isomorphism,
and so $A$ is a product of finitely many fields, and hence has Krull dimension zero.